# How to get list of Wishlist product on popup in homepage?

Tags: wishlist, magento2.4.1, popup, magento-2-commerce

I have added a wishlist icon on my header, I need to show my list of wishlist product if customer click the wishlist icon as a popup. Any reference thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Block file on following location:

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\WishlistProducts.php

```
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;
    
    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory as WishlistCollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Session,
    
    
    class WishlistProducts extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
        protected $_customerSession;
        protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    
        public function __construct(Context $context,
            CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
            WishlistCollectionFactory $wishlistCollectionFactory,
            Session $customerSessio
        ) {
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
            $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $wishlistCollectionFactory;
            $this->_customerSession = $customerSessio;
        }
        
        public function getWishlistProductCollection()
        {
            $collection = [];
            if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $wishlist = $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                    ->addCustomerIdFilter($this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
    
                $productIds = null;
                foreach ($wishlist as $product) {
                    $productIds[] = $product->getProductId();
                }
                
                $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($productIds);
                $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId());
            }
            return $collection;
        }
    }
```

2. now create phtml file and assign above block class, and then do code like this :

   ```
   <?php
       $collection = $block->getWishlistProductCollection();
       foreach ($collection as $_product) 
       {
               echo $product->getName();
               echo $product->getProductUrl();
       }
   ```

Comment: I want to show my wishlist on popup window, my code : https://codeshare.io/29oQY0 its not working, can u pls help me on this.

Comment: path : Path: app\design\frontend\Zero\my_theme\Magento_Theme\templates\location_link.phtml,

Comment: yes you can do the code into the proper block file and use the code here.

Comment: Bro, i am getting strange error, on my home page, copyright not getting full width, but other pages its getting full width, https://i.imgur.com/P0WClFw.png what is the possibilities error.

Comment: If you have new question then ask it separately. if above answer help you then mark as solution and upvote, so it help other into community

Comment: sure, understood.

Comment: For wishlist is it necessary to create a layout.xml file.

Comment: yes to specify that block for the template file that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the article: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/get-wishlist-products-collection-magento-2.html
Please tell me if it helps!